# android regex error

Tags: android, regex

That is my text i want to do regex

```
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048725/ocamllex-regex-syntax-error'

},
```

That is normal form of regex

```
url:\s'(.*)'\s*},
```

Yhat is inside eclipse version with escape

```
url:\\s'(.*)'\\s*},
```

but android studio gives error.

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index :
```

It shows last letter. `,`

this `,` is faulty.

i define patter like this

```
 pattern = "url:\s'(.*)'\s*},"
```

Why?

I also used with backslash but still same. This time it shows `\` in front of coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url:\\s'(.*)'\\s*\\},
```

You need to escape `{}` as well.

Comment: Thanks it worked. In eclipse java, it was not problem.